# How can I center a div inside a div?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a contact list but can't wrap my head around it. I want to vertically center the detailspanel:

```
.contactpanel .icon
{
    background: url('http://www.alter-net.info/Person.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: 14px 14px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}

.contactpanel .detailspanel
{
    margin-left: 65px;
}
```

It's on JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hu6wq7km/

I want the details (name and email) to be centered vertically inside the panel, how can I accomplish that?

Comment: How many times can these questions be asked? Search the site, this question (and some very similar) have been asked tons of times before. Search the site before posting a question, it would be quicker doing that then writing this question.

Comment: @Ruddy: I was just thinking that myself!!!

Comment: for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers?rq=1

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hu6wq7km/6/  is this do y want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the height is unknown you could use the "table trick" to vertically center your content.

Link to JSbin: http://jsfiddle.net/9xqdtbqu/

CSS:

```
.contactpanel
{
    display:table;
}

.contactpanel .icon
{
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;      

}

.contactpanel .detailspanel
{
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;    
}
```

Comment: Thank you Linus! Just what I needed. Setting them to act as good ol' table was cool!

Answer (score 0):

Using padding top and bottom you can do this, add padding to detailpanel

update your css for class detailspanel

```
.contactpanel .detailspanel
{
    margin-left: 65px;
    padding: 12px 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hu6wq7km/5/

Answer (score 0):

Or as an alternative you could try this:

```
.contactpanel .detailspanel {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 40px;
    margin: auto 0 auto 65px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the height of the `contactpanel` which is `60px` and you have a `div` with `id` `detailspanel`. Simple padding will adjust the `detailspanel` in `center`.

try with `padding : 10px` which will adjust the `detailspanel` to center.

To adjust with complete control of the elements on the page. set the individual `div's` of `name` and `email` to a height of `15px` without any `padding` and `margin: 10px`, this will do the trick. Since the `margin-bottom` and `margin-top` of `name` and `email` div will collapse.

Answer (score 0):

Add position absolute for the div.detailspanel like below:

```
.contactpanel .detailspanel
{
    margin-left: 74px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 11px;
}
```

For your reference check this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hu6wq7km/9/